# Including "implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.4'" causes app to crash at startup every time

Tags: android, firebase-analytics

Here is the Logcat:

```
2020-07-29 15:36:26.382 1382-8050/? I/ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=XXX bnds=[586,1002][855,1440]} from uid 10156
2020-07-29 15:36:26.386 878-878/? D/android.hardware.power@1.3-service.pixel-libperfmgr: LAUNCH: 1
2020-07-29 15:36:26.390 1382-1382/? V/SettingsProvider: Notifying for 0: content://settings/secure/reminder_exp_learning_time_elapsed
2020-07-29 15:36:26.415 845-845/? D/Zygote: Forked child process 3895
2020-07-29 15:36:26.416 3895-3895/? I/XXX: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2020-07-29 15:36:26.416 1382-1417/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 3895:XXX/u0a210 for activity {XXX}
2020-07-29 15:36:26.427 3895-3895/? E/XXX: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2020-07-29 15:36:26.594 3895-3895/XXX I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
2020-07-29 15:36:26.594 3895-3895/XXX I/MultiDex: Installing application
2020-07-29 15:36:26.594 3895-3895/XXX I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
    
    --------- beginning of crash
2020-07-29 15:36:26.612 3895-3933/X E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: ScionFrontendApi
    Process: X, PID: 3895XX
    java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field PREFER_LOCAL of type Lcom/google/android/gms/dynamite/DynamiteModule$VersionPolicy; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/dynamite/DynamiteModule; or its superclasses (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule' appears in /data/app/XXX-9lVbsCQwO59OkXDFYFHDjg==/base.apk)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzag.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api@@17.4.4:54)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzaj.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api@@17.4.4:12)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzag$zzb.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api@@17.4.4:11)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
2020-07-29 15:36:26.614 1382-3941/? I/DropBoxManagerService: add tag=data_app_crash isTagEnabled=true flags=0x2
2020-07-29 15:36:26.615 1382-8050/? W/ActivityTaskManager:   Force finishing activity XXX/XXX
```

Commenting out this line in the app/build.gradle

```
//    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.4'
```

causes the problem to go away and the app starts normally.

Does

```
"AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: ScionFrontendApi"
```

mean anything to anyone?

How about this:
'java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field PREFER_LOCAL of type
Lcom/google/android/gms/dynamite/DynamiteModule$VersionPolicy;
in class Lcom/google/android/gms/dynamite/DynamiteModule'
?

```
Thank you.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you follow the steps in adding the firebase-analytics dependency as the docs [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add-config-file)?

as it look like some missing attributes in an inner module.

edit:
Lowering the version of the firebase-analytics dependency to a older version (17.3.0) took care of the error.

Comment: Yes, followed it to the letter.

Comment: @jeka how about trying to lower the version of the firebase-analytics dependency to a older version like 17.3.0

Comment: That seems to have taken care of the error - the app starts up fine now. I did have to downgrade com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api to 17.3.0 as well. Can you explain why dependency on firebase-analytics 17.3.0 works while 17.4.4 crashes?

Comment: Glad to hear that, it is the latest update as per the release notes, so it may have some issues. I recommed you to open an issue with your stacktrace and device info for the firebase team to check it out https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues

Answer (score 3):

For me adding the following lines to proguard rules seems to have fixed it.

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Appears to be from FirebaseAnalytics (FlutterFire) and some version conflicts. Only happened on release builds. [This comment](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/8416#issuecomment-1091668005) had the answer.

Locking in the Firebase versions in pubspec.yaml worked for me.

```yaml
  firebase_core: 1.13.1 
  firebase_messaging: 11.2.11
  firebase_analytics: 9.1.0
```

Comment: Kill me, please. I haven't seen worst soft ever

Comment: Yeah.....it's pretty unfortunate. The tools, when working, are great. It's just untangling their crazy dependency tree.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove/comment this line in the app/build.gradle will fix the issue

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx"
```

Looks like dependency issues in the firebase-analytics.