# Flutter release application crashes on startup

Tags: android, flutter, apk

When I run the app in debug mode it works fine but after generate signed bundle/ APK release, The app crashed when start up app.
And I tried to flutter run in release mode and show this console.

```
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk (14.9MB).
Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...
E/AndroidRuntime(11195): FATAL EXCEPTION: ScionFrontendApi
E/AndroidRuntime(11195): Process: app.datossolutions.sabaya_captain, PID: 11195
E/AndroidRuntime(11195): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/AndroidRuntime(11195):    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.o3.<init>(Unknown Source:34)
E/AndroidRuntime(11195):    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.k2.<init>(:3)
E/AndroidRuntime(11195):    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.k2.G(:4)
E/AndroidRuntime(11195):    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.AppMeasurementDynamiteService.initialize(:2)
E/AndroidRuntime(11195):    at f.e.a.c.f.k.o0.a(:6)
E/AndroidRuntime(11195):    at f.e.a.c.f.k.E0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/AndroidRuntime(11195):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/AndroidRuntime(11195):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/AndroidRuntime(11195):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:929)
E/AndroidRuntime(11195): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.h.values []
E/AndroidRuntime(11195):    at java.lang.Enum.enumValues(Enum.java:270)
E/AndroidRuntime(11195):    at java.lang.Enum.access$000(Enum.java:61)
E/AndroidRuntime(11195):    at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:277)
E/AndroidRuntime(11195):    at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:275)
E/AndroidRuntime(11195):    at libcore.util.BasicLruCache.get(BasicLruCache.java:63)
E/AndroidRuntime(11195):    at java.lang.Enum.getSharedConstants(Enum.java:289)
E/AndroidRuntime(11195):    at java.lang.Class.getEnumConstantsShared(Class.java:2428)
E/AndroidRuntime(11195):    at java.util.EnumMap.getKeyUniverse(EnumMap.java:755)
E/AndroidRuntime(11195):    at java.util.EnumMap.<init>(EnumMap.java:138)
E/AndroidRuntime(11195):    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.i.<init>(Unknown Source:7)
E/AndroidRuntime(11195):    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.i.<clinit>(Unknown Source:3)
E/AndroidRuntime(11195):    ... 9 more
E/AndroidRuntime(11195): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.h.values []
E/AndroidRuntime(11195):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2072)
E/AndroidRuntime(11195):    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2050)
E/AndroidRuntime(11195):    at java.lang.Enum.enumValues(Enum.java:267)
E/AndroidRuntime(11195):    ... 19 more
E/AndroidRuntime(11440): FATAL EXCEPTION: ScionFrontendApi
E/AndroidRuntime(11440): Process: app.datossolutions.sabaya_captain, PID: 11440
E/AndroidRuntime(11440): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/AndroidRuntime(11440):    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.o3.<init>(Unknown Source:34)
E/AndroidRuntime(11440):    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.k2.<init>(:3)
E/AndroidRuntime(11440):    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.k2.G(:4)
E/AndroidRuntime(11440):    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.AppMeasurementDynamiteService.initialize(:2)
E/AndroidRuntime(11440):    at f.e.a.c.f.k.o0.a(:6)
E/AndroidRuntime(11440):    at f.e.a.c.f.k.E0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/AndroidRuntime(11440):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
```

Comment: Can you share your pubspec.yaml file/describe what packages you are using?

Comment: seems to be firebase lib issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63162392/including-implementation-com-google-firebasefirebase-analytics17-4-4-cause/71876935#71876935

Comment: @HardikMehta thanks for your help , it's work as well

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the error is related to Firebase setup. Check out the guide on the official [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).

Verify if you added correctly the following lines:

`build.gradle`

```
buildscript {

  repositories {
    // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
    google()  // Google's Maven repository
  }

  dependencies {
    // ...

    // Add the following line:
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'  // Google Services plugin
  }
}

allprojects {
  // ...

  repositories {
    // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
    google()  // Google's Maven repository
    // ...
  }
}
```

`app/build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
// Add the following line:
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  // Google Services plugin

android {
  // ...
}
```

After doing so, run a `flutter clean` and a `flutter pub get` and rebuild.